# how to launch a web url and extract the id for its using flutter web app

Tags: flutter

Consider http://example in my web application.My host url is ae.

I give each store a QR code, and when they scan it, they will see something like http://example.ae/a23bc, which includes the store's unique identifier.

When someone scans and launches a web application, they receive a 404 error because the route was not found.

I need to extract the user's id from the address url when they login, and I simply want to launch the basic url while ignoring the user's id. I want to produce and represent data using an API, so id is simply for extracting and using this.

any one know the best way to do this in Flutter Web

lauch the base url http"//exapmle.ae
ignoring the id
and i want to save the id in my for further functioning

Comment: Can you change the QR to http://example.ae/?id=a23bc If so, you can grab the query parameter in `main()` and then use it when you need it later in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set the route like this

```
http://example.ae/home?uniqueId=yourUniqueId
```

you should also use the

```
onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
```

of the MaterialApp in order to parse the queryParameters from the visited web page, like this

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
RoutingData routingData = settings.name!.getRoutingData;

 switch (routingData.route) {
  case AppRoutes.homeRoute:
   return _getPageRoute(
      HomeView(
        homeController: sl(),
      ),
      settings);
  case AppRoutes.blog:
    return _getPageRoute(const ViewBlogs(), settings);
  case AppRoutes.blogPost:
    log("Going Blog Post ${routingData.route} post id 
     ${routingData['id']}");
      return _getPageRoute(
       BlogDetailPage(
         postId: routingData['id'],
       ),
       settings);
```

this being the routing data class

```
class RoutingData {
 final String route;
 final Map<String, String> _queryParameters;

 RoutingData({
  required this.route,
  required Map<String, String> queryParameters,
 }) : _queryParameters = queryParameters;

 operator [](String key) => _queryParameters[key];
 }
```

and using a extension on the String class, of the settings.name you can get the RoutingData

```
 extension StringExtension on String {
  RoutingData get getRoutingData {
    var uriData = Uri.parse(this);
    //  print('queryParameters: ${uriData.queryParameters} path: 
    ${uriData.path}');
     return RoutingData(
      queryParameters: uriData.queryParameters,
      route: uriData.path,
     );
   }
  }
```

Comment: Actually the url is auto generated based on qr scanning I append the id with base URL so the user can easily open the web app with their unique id 
final URL seems like HTTP://example.ae/store_id. and base URL is HTTP://example.ae